# Mixing Asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit with Twitter bootstrap, will it give conflicts or problems?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, twitter-bootstrap, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Someone have mixed these two before? Could it give problems having an Update Panel with twitter bootstrap and ajax control toolkit controls mixed in? Any conflicts when using one or another ajax functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i have seen a considerable problem.

- If you have master pages with ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager it
  forces you to enclose it in a form with runat="server". The problem
  is that later when you want to use little forms with the twitter
  bootstrap form's classes (for login, data input, etc) the html
  validation warns that you cannot put forms inside forms and chrome
  for example removes the inner forms tags...and if you replace the
  forms tag with div tag and apply the twitter bootstrap form's classes
  it loses the margin bottom given by the twitter bootstrap css to the
  form elements...

Comment: For the "inner" forms, just use divs like this `<div class="form-horizontal"></div>`. Bootstrap doesn't care that they aren't actually `form` tags.